# Recover data from corrupt NTFS drive - TrueCrypt

Tags: windows, ntfs, truecrypt, partition-recovery, testdisk

Background: Visual Studio 2017 was release two days ago, 2017-03-07, and to get a clean install I decided to format and reinstall my OS, Windows 10.

For my storage disk, I use TrueCrypt 7.1a. After formatting my OS-hard drive, reinstalling Windows 10 and TrueCrypt the errors started. When I mounted the hard drive in TrueCrypt it said that my `Volume Header` was corrupt and that I needed to restore it. After doing so I saw a new drive like before but I got the error `You need to format the disk in drive X: before you can use it`.

I then tried running `NTFS Data Recovery Toolkit v. 8` and `TestDisk 7.0` to recover my partition but this failed. I only got the error below which I don't know what it means from TestDisk Dump.

[image]

```
A disk error occurred...BMKRI is missing...BMKRI is compressed...Press Ctrl+Alt+Del to restart
```

When this failed I installed TrueCrypt 7.2 and managed to decrypt the hard drive. When checking my storage drive now my new error is: `E:\ is not accessible. The parameter is incorrect`.

[image]

If I try to run `chkdsk` I get the following message:

```
The type of the file system is NTFS.
Unable to determine volume version and state.  CHKDSK aborted.
```

[image]

In `Disk Management` the disk is marked as File System `RAW`:

[image]

I then tried `NTFS Data Recovery Toolkit` again and now I could actually see my content! I used the tool Active@ Partion recovery and QuickScan/SuperScan. The only error that I can see is `Overlapped partition detected`.

[image]

My question now is where do I go from here? I do not wan't to risk anything now that I have gotten this far.

**Update:**

Tried this guide to restore a partition, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O_kvJF87Drc

TestDisk -> Create -> Select Disk -> Proceed -> Intel -> Quick Search -> Enter -> Write -> Reboot.

I still can't view the disk in Windows but in `NTFS Data Recovery` the `Recovery Status` changed to `Existing Volume` and the drive is now marked as green instead of red.

[image]

Comment: If you can browse the content, first of all make a copy of it into a clean and working drive. Then attempt whatever you want to attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up doing a `Deeper Search` in TestDisk which resulted in a lot of partitions. First tried making one NTFS partition Primary bootable and delete the others. When this did not work I did the scan again and selected the other NTFS partition as primary bootable but it did not work either.

[image]

Since most of my files were backed up I used the freeware `Recuva` set to `Deep Scan` and `Scan for non-deleted files` and recovered the two files I was unsure about. If I needed the entire partition I would have bought `Active@ Partion recovery` from `NTFS Data Recovery Toolkit` but since I only needed two files this seemed unnecessary.

[image]